# On the power tower $\exp(x-\exp(x-\cdots))$

Tags: exponential-function, power-towers

The intention is to find the maximum of the power tower $\exp(x-\exp(x-\cdots))$. From [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vivhppbq7r), we see that it is around $0.965$ or possibly even higher. The approximate value of its integral is also given for interest.

Since $\exp(x-\exp(x-\cdots))$ has this shape in the link for every two iterations, $$\exp(x-\exp(x-\cdots))=k\implies \exp(x-\exp(x-k))=k$$ not $\exp(x-k)=k$.

But we face a problem, how do we write $k$ purely in terms of $x$?

Comment: For $x=1$ you can see that $e^{x-e^{x-k}}=k$ has a solution for $k=1$. So the maximum should be 1 or higher.

Comment: It seems that the integral from $0$ to $1$ is approx   $0.77203095$ ? (Based on my proposal for the powerseries) Desmos gives some smaller value, but the difference to my value si surely based on insufficient iteration in the representation of the function in Desmos (try higher iterations to see approximations to my value).

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thank you for your attempt. But as I have said to J.G., the iteration $f_{k+1}(x)=\exp(x-f_k(x))$ is not the same as $$f_{k+1}(x)=\exp(x-\exp(x-f_k(x)))$$ as the integral fluctuates for odd iterations.

Comment: Well, doing the expansion $u_0=\exp(x)$, $t_0=\exp(x-u_0)$,$u_1 = \exp(x-t_0)$ and so on for $n$ iterations it shows, that for $n \to \infty$ not only $u_n - u_{n+1}$ and $t_n-t_{n+1}$ converge to zero, but also $u_n-t_n$ converge to zero. For $x=0.8$ I found improvement of one significant digit for $k \approx 12$ steps, so for this range $0<x<=1$ we have for $n \to \infty$ that in the limit indeed $u_n=t_n$ so we can identify the short version of the iteration $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}=\exp(x-f_n)=\exp(x-\exp(x-f_n))$ . The purpose of 3. picture in my answer was to visualize just this.

Comment: For more derivation of the problem of convergence $t_n \to u_n$ you might like to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050819/1714 espec. the answer of Henning Makholm

Comment: You may look at the value $3\omega^2$ where $\omega e^{\omega}=1$.Good day!

Comment: Your desmos link does not load on mobile

Answer (score 2):

***(0)*** $\qquad$ Let basically $f_0(x)=\exp(x)$ and 
then iterate $f_{k+1}(x)=\exp(x-f_k(x))$ a couple of times and assume $f(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$

---

***(I)*** $\qquad$ First we assume all that in terms of a formal powerseries. Then this converges to something like 
$$ f_\infty(x) \approx    +0.567143290410  \\
            +0.361896256635 x^{1} \\
           +0.0736778051764 x^{2} \\
         -0.00134285965499 x^{3} \\
         -0.00163606514791 x^{4} \\
         +0.000232149655570 x^{5} \\
        +0.0000474223203353 x^{6} \\
       -0.0000189444233824 x^{7} \\
    -0.0000000208785458195 x^{8} \\
       +0.00000117699067908 x^{9} \\
    -0.000000179633602646 x^{10} \\
   -0.0000000510936764494 x^{11} \\
    +0.0000000206028966316 x^{12} \\
  +0.000000000306827812731 x^{13} \\
  -0.00000000154503877033 x^{14} \\
 + O(x^{15}) $$
using Pari/GP. Setting $x=1$ it approximates nicely the value $f(1)=1$.    Moreover, for $x=0$ it gives immediately the value $\omega=0.5671432...=W(1)$

---

***(II)*** $\qquad$ If we say $t:=f_\infty(x) $ and $t=\exp(x-t)$ then we can derive $t \exp(t) = \exp(x)$ and thus $ t=W(\exp(x)) = f_\infty(x) $ and this is $1$ for $x=1$ and $\omega$ for $x=0$ as before.

---

***(III)*** $\qquad$ If we use the basic definition (but not as powerseries but as evaluated values) and take the mean $g_k = (f_k(x) + f_{k+1}(x))/2$ for some (high) iteration $k$ then $err_k(x)= g_k(x) -f_\infty(x) $ shows a small difference-curve increasing with $x \to 1$ but accordingly and in concurrence decreasing with $k \to \infty$ , so it seems also by this limiting-process that the definition of the limit using the Lambert-W-definition makes sense.

---

For ***(III)*** see the following pictures. The first picture shows $f_{101}(x),f_{102}(x),f_\infty(x),err_{101}(x)$ It makes visually that it makes sense to look at the mean of the alternating values $f_{101}(x)$ and $f_{102}$, and also, that the difference of the mean and the $f_\infty(x)$ is small but increasing somewhat when $x \to 1$ (the scale for the *err*-curve is at the rhs of the picture).
[image: picture101]

The second picture shows $f_{501}(x),f_{502}(x),f_\infty(x),err_{501}(x)$ and we see, that the two curves approximate the $f_\infty(x)$ curve much more which is displayed in the smaller $err_{501}(x)$
[image: picture501]

The third picture shows the rate of convergence improving by iterations. I use the value $x_0=0.8$ and document $t_n(x_0)=f_{2n}(x_0)$ and  $u_n(x_0)=f_{2n+1}(x_0)$ for $1$ to $128$ iterations. We see that $t_n()$ and $u_n()$ converge well and the difference decreases by about one significant decimal digits by ca 12 iterations.
[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

We have  $\exp(x-\exp(x-k))=k$

Taking logarithm on both side we get :

$$xe^k-e^x=e^k\ln(k)$$

Your equality is of the form $(a,b,c\ne0)$:
$$ae^x+bx+c=0$$
Where $a=-1$ , $b=e^k$ and $c=-e^k\ln(k)$

Let us find the general solution .

First it's equivalent to :
$$\frac{a}{b}e^x+x+\frac{c}{b}=0$$
Or 
$$\frac{a}{b}e^x=-\left(x+\frac{c}{b}\right)$$
Or:
$$\frac{b}{a}e^{-x}\left(-\left(x+\frac{c}{b}\right)\right)=1$$
Or:
$$e^{-x-\frac{c}{b}}\left(-\left(x+\frac{c}{b}\right)\right)=\frac{a}{b}e^{-\frac{c}{b}}$$

Put $u=-x-\frac{c}{b}$ and $v=\frac{a}{b}e^{-\frac{c}{b}}$ wich gets :

$$ue^u=v$$

Then use the definition of the lambert function to have :$$x=f(k)$$

Next to get :

$$g(x)=k$$

You can use as primary tool the [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInversionTheorem.html)

Comment: How is it of the form $ae^x+bx+c=0$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt take the logarithm and multiply by $e^k$  in $\exp(x-\exp(x-k))=k$

Comment: If you down vote please explain !

Comment: I have already explained. I ask why do you think this is of the form $ae^x+bx+c=0$. If you plot the provided equation and read it carefully, you will realize the question is **not** asking for solutions to $k=\exp(x-k)$, if that is what you are referring to. Furthermore, the solution to such an equation is far simpler than what you have written, so again, do not see how your answer is helpful.

Comment: You've edited your comment in the time that I have replied, and when following your steps, I get $$xe^k-e^x=e^k\ln(k)$$ which is not at all like the form which you use in your question. Please be specific as to what your $a,b,c$ are as well as your steps to getting there, and avoid unconstructive comments such as "Are you serious?"

Comment: My bad, it was unclear where you were headed before the edit. You may want to make it clearer that you intended to solve for $x$ instead of $k$, and the inverting the result, as well as how you are getting your initial equation.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt    No problem you are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

**Series expansion for $k$**

Via [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):
$$k=e^{x-e^{x-k}} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{nx}}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}e^{-e^ke^{-w}}\right|_0$$

A [table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=table%5Blim%5BD%5B%28e%5E%28p+e%5E-w%29%29%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2Cw-%3E0%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C12%7D%5D) of derivatives implies [Stirling S2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=StirlingS2):

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}e^{pe^{-w}}\right|_0=(-1)^{n+1}e^p\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}s_{n-1}^{(m)}p^m$$

We notice this sum is formula [$(14)$’s Bell polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html). Therefore:

$$\bbox[5px, border:1px dashed blue]{k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\operatorname B_{n-1}(-ne^x)}{e^{(e^x-x)n}n!}}$$

[First 10](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28x-exp%28x-exp%28x-exp%28x-exp%28x-exp%28x%29%29%29%29%29%29%2Csum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28n-1%29%2Fn%21+e%5E%28%28x-+e%5Ex%29n%29+BellB%28n-1%2C-ne%5Ex%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D) partial sums in purple and 3rd iteration of $\exp(x-\exp(\dots))$ in blue:

[image]

**Integration**

Integrating the function may require an expansion or two and the maximum, when [graphing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/csab6qwpem) $k=e^{x-e^{x-k}}$, is $(1,1)$. The [incomplete gamma function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Gamma+Wolfram+Language) gives:

$$\int e^{sx}e^{-n e^x}dx=-\frac{\Gamma(s,ne^x)}{n^s}$$

so we use the [2,3 argument gamma regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Gammaregularized) function:

$$\bbox[5px, border:1px dashed blue]{\int k(x) dx=C-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\frac{s_{n-1}^{(m-n)}(-1)^mQ(m,ne^x)}{n^{n+1}}\\\int_0^1 k(x)dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\frac{s_{n-1}^{(m-n)}(-1)^m Q(m,en,n)}{n^{n+1}}\approx 0.763}$$

The series converges more slowly near $x=1$, so here is a [evaluator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bsum%5Bsum%5BGamma%28m%2Bn%2Ce+n%2Cn%29%2F%28n%5En+n%21%29+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2Bm%29+stirlings2%28n-1%2Cm%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C84%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C85%7D%5D%2C10%5D)   for the integral on $[0,1]$. Also, the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%22-4%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22sum%5Bsum%5BGamma%28m%2Bn%2Cn+e%5Ex%29%2F%28n%5E%28m%2Bn%29+n%21%29+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2Bm-1%29+stirlings2%28n-1%2Cm%29+n%5Em%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C8%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C8%7D%5D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%224%22) when $C=0$ is:

[image]

**Area under graph**

Since $\int_{\Bbb R} e^{sx-ne^x}dx=\frac{\Gamma(s)}{n^s}$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty k(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{m+n-1}s_{n-1}^{(m)}n^m}{n!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(m+n)x}e^{-ne^x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{(m+n-1)!(-1)^{m+n-1}s_{n-1}^{(m)}}{n^n n!}$$

and [OEIS result](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C18%2C384&language=english&go=Search) $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{m+n-1} (m+n-1)! s_{n-1}^{(m)}=\frac{n^{n-2}}{n!}$ gives a [numerically plausible](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%CF%80%5E2%2F6%2Csum%5Bsum%5B%28m%2Bn-1%29%21%2Fn%5E%28m%2Bn%29+%2Fn%21+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2Bm-1%29++stirlings2%28n-1%2Cm%29+n%5Em%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C120%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C120%7D%5D%7D) result:

$$\bbox[5px, border:1px dashed blue]{\int_{\Bbb R}\exp(x-\exp(x-\dots))dx=\frac{\pi^2}6}$$

Answer (score 0):

You've noted $k=e^{x-k}$ so $ke^k=e^x$. In terms of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), $k=W(e^x)$. The main question is which branch choice we take as our definition of the tower.

Comment: No, it's not $k=\exp(x-k)$, it's $k=\exp(x-\exp(x-k))$! As I have said, the integral only converges for every *two* iterations, that's why I am asking